# My vacuum(s) cannot be pushed on my newly installed carpet

Tags: flooring

We just had Innovia carpet (Carpet One) installed and when my wife tried to vacuum she could not push the vacuum over the carpet, seemed to suck up into the vacuum.  This was a Shark.  She then tried to use an old, height adjustable Hoover and had the same result.  A friend of mine, who used to install carpet, said it may not have been stretched properly.  Is this true?

Comment: Did you adjust the brush height?

Comment: Our vacuum didn't have a adjustable height, so I had to physically modify it to make it higher to deal with new carpet.  This was a Dyson, so even vacs that claim to be very nice can have significant shortcomings.  We could only pull the vac over the floor before the modification.

Comment: I have the same problem. The reason is that the carpet backing is plastic and will not allow air to pass through. So the vacuum sucks-up the carpet tight against the vacuum. It is no different holding your hand over the end of the vacuum hose. I haven't yet figured-out how to properly vacuum this carpet. It is water-proof, but impossible to vacuum.?????????

Answer (score 1):

Try going at it from a different direction. I have a low-pile rug that refuses to be vacuumed from one direction. Even while it's off, you can't push it that way.

Also, try pulling and never pushing; tip it up to advance, then let it touch down and pull backwards. Again, one direction is probably easier than the other.

If it wasn't stretched well, you'd probably be bunching it up just walking on it, so I think you'd know. Stomp your way towards a wall, if it bunches up, it's not stretched right.